# Codeigniter "No tables used", get_where()

Tags: codeigniter, get, where-clause

So, i'm trying to create a function that removes a post, and inserts the values into a table named "removed_post".
Now, i get the error:

```
No tables used
SELECT *
Line Number: 330
```

What causes this? I have google'd it ALOT, and tried different "answers", without any success.

Here is my code:

```
class Remove extends CI_Controller {


function post($id = null) {

$this->db->get_where('comments', array('id' => $id));
$query = $this->db->get();
$data = array(
'amne_id' => $query->row()->amne_id,
'user_id' => $query->row()->user_id,
'date_created' => $query->row()->date,
            );
 $this->db->insert('removed_post', $data);
 $this->db->delete('comments', array('id' => $id));
 redirect('/');
}
```

EDIT: And yes, the code is not optimized.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->get_where('comments', array('id' => $id));
$query = $this->db->get();
```

should be:

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('comments', array('id' => $id));
```

In your code the first query is run but you are not capturing the result. The second line tries to capture results for a blank query. `get_where()` calls `get()` for you so you don't have to call it explicitly.

**new error**

```
$row = $query->row();
$data = array(
  'amne_id' => $row->amne_id,
  'user_id' => $row->user_id,
  'date_created' => $row->date,
);
```

Comment: Alright, thank you for answering. Though, i have tried that too, and i get another error now: "Trying to get property of non-object" on each of the object in the array.

Comment: It may be that your query isn't bringing back any results, causing an error. Try wrapping @John Conde's above code in a conditional statement so it will only run if there are results: `if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {}`

Comment: What you said made me check the code again, and i noticed that i was taking the wrong id on the post, so the query didn't find any result. Thank you! It works now :)